# How to create a event where it announces if there is a certain amount of members? (Discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

So basically, my server is about to hit 100 members, and I wanna make a @client.event (if not event then command) where it detects when 100 members is hit, and if it is, it announces it in my announcement channel. I've searched everywhere for it but i've never gotten a result! Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would really only need to check if the guild has 100 members if a new member joins (or leaves, but that would be a bit depressing). For that, you can use the [`on_member_join()` event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join).

Make sure that member intents are enabled, both in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (in the section called **Bot**, under *Privileged Gateway Intents*), as well as in your script.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Enable member intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

CHANNEL_ID = 1234567890

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    if member.guild.member_count == 100:
        await channel.send("100 Members! :partying_face:")
```

`CHANNEL_ID` would be the ID of the channel to send the celebratory message in.